# How to analyze perf sched script and perf sched latency?

Tags: linux, perf

I used perf sched record to record something.

and I got some ***context switch*** event from **perf sched script**

```
filebench  2646 [000] 21159.177699:       sched:sched_switch: filebench:2646 [120] **R** ==> rcu_sched:8 [120]

filebench  2611 [000] 21159.172060:       sched:sched_switch: filebench:2611 [120] **T** ==> filebench:2645 [120]

filebench  2618 [000] 21159.193692:       sched:sched_switch: filebench:2618 [120] **S** ==> rcu_sched:8 [120]

filebench  2620 [000] 21159.193724:       sched:sched_switch: filebench:2620 [120] **D** ==> filebench:2628 [120]
```

whats the mean of the characters R/T/S/D ?

Another question:
why the cs time is different between perf sched latency and perf sched script?

Comment: sorry for my bad format..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters `R/T/S/D` represent various task states.

The character 'R' shows that the task is in **TASK_RUNNING** State. The character 'S' shows that the task has been put to **TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE** state. The character 'D' shows that the task has been put to **TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE** state by the scheduler. Finally the character 'T' shows that the task is currently in **TASK_STOPPED** state. To understand how the task states can be determined from the characters, look up the linux kernel (4.17) source code:-

[TASK_STATE_TO_CHAR_STR macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/builtin-sched.c#L84)

```
#define TASK_STATE_TO_CHAR_STR "RSDTtZXxKWP"

/* task state bitmask, copied from include/linux/sched.h */
#define TASK_RUNNING        0
#define TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE  1
#define TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE    2
#define __TASK_STOPPED      4
#define __TASK_TRACED       8
/* in tsk->exit_state */
#define EXIT_DEAD       16
#define EXIT_ZOMBIE     32
#define EXIT_TRACE      (EXIT_ZOMBIE | EXIT_DEAD)
/* in tsk->state again */
#define TASK_DEAD       64
#define TASK_WAKEKILL       128
#define TASK_WAKING     256
#define TASK_PARKED     512
```

This is as simple as referring the first character 'R' to the first kind of task state -- i.e. `TASK_RUNNING`, the second character 'S' to the `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state, similarly the third character 'D' refers to `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` ... this goes on and in the end 'W' refers to `TASK_WAKING` and 'P' refers to `TASK_PARKED`. Note that the task state `EXIT_TRACE` does not correspond to any of the characters in the macro string `TASK_STATE_TO_CHAR_STR`.

For your second question, it is quite hard to see which output represents `perf sched latency` and which output represents `perf sched script`. It is also hard to see how you are analyzing both the outputs. You have to remember that `perf sched latency` summarizes scheduler latencies by task. It shows you for each task, what is its maximum delay, what was its runtime and how many times during its execution was there a context switch apart from some other details. `perf sched script` on the other hand will dump all scheduler events analogous to `perf script` command.

The two commands are very different and any direct comparison is bound to lead to incorrect conclusions.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer !    I used "perf sched script | grep 'sched:sched_switch: filebench' | wc -l  " to count the cs times of filebench and compared it to perf sched latency data.    So the perf sched script cs times includes the cs inside the multi-thread tasks?        And perf sched latency just counts the cs between tasks?

Comment: I also used the same command to count cs times of a single thread task in perf sched script.   And the cs times between script and latency is really different while the latency just counted 1 cs.

Comment: A question about this has already been raised: [here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-perf-users/msg05210.html) - does this apply to you as well ? Basically latency is looking for wakeup events to count the number of context switches.